# объекты создаются близко друг к другу

Tags: c#, unity3d

при создание нескольких объектов,они ложатся друг на друга,как сделать их спавн на расстояние друг от друга?

```
{
public GameObject platformPrefab;
public GameObject Canvas;
public GameObject obj;


void Start()
{
    Vector3 SpawnerPosition = new Vector3();    

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)                
    {
        SpawnerPosition.x = Random.Range(-370f, 370);
        SpawnerPosition.y += Random.Range(-615f, 615f);

        GameObject obj = Instantiate(platformPrefab, SpawnerPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        obj.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Это задача такая же, как генератор "уникальных случайных чисел", позиция нового объекта должна быть за пределами уже созданного.

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать список, каждый раз при создании объекта добавляем SpawnerPosition в этот список. И дальше перемещаем весь код из for в отдельную функцию, внутри функции дописываем if и внутри него проверяем нет ли позиции в списке с позициями, если есть выполняем функцию заново, если нет делаем наши действия.